# Changing URL in Android MP3 service MediaPlayer

Tags: android, service, stream, mp3, switch-statement

I have a Service which starts playing MP3 stream in background in Android. There is a menu activity with channels select, and player activity, which starts to play the MP3 selected by button click.
It uses MediaPlayer class. Here is how URL starts.

```
mp3Service.playSong(getBaseContext(),url);
```

Now, when coming back to the menu with URLs, I want to change the URL playing. I'd prefer not to stop the service and only change it's URL. Is it possible? I've read documentation of MediaPlayer, but not sure what to do, tried some variants.

How to switch to another URL?
mp3Service.pauseSong(getBaseContext());

Then STOP, and mp3Service.playSong(getBaseContext(),newurl)?

```
////////////////////////////// PART OF THE CLASS

 public String currenturl="";

public void playSong(Context c, String url) {
        if (currenturl.equals(""))
        {
        if(!created){
            this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
            created = true;
            currenturl=url;
        }
            this.mplayer.start();
        }
        else
            {
            if (!currenturl.equals(url))
            {

                if(!created){
                    this.mplayer.stop();
                    this.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(c, Uri.parse(url));
                    created = true;
                    currenturl=url;
                }
                    this.mplayer.start();


            }

            };
    }

public void pauseSong(Context c) {
        this.mplayer.pause();
    }

    //
    public void stopSong(Context c) {
        this.mplayer.stop();
    }
```

Not so easy...

Comment: Seems fine to me although you can also just call stop without calling pause. Are you experiencing any problems with this approach? You definitely do not need to stop the service. You can also reuse the MediaPlayer object by using `setDataSource()`

Comment: All my previous attempts (different) were not successful. Now I'm trying to do accurately. The problem also is to determine whether the clicked url is new. If no, we keep playing, if yes the player must stop. Now the play is on clicklistener, but I want it to start activity onCreate. Will try...

Comment: OK, this wasn't clear from your question. I would store the currently playing URL as a String in my service, then I can easily check if a new one `.equals()` the current one.

Comment: Thanks, and how you recommend to store a String? If I need to change the current URL, Java won't give me to change the String.

Comment: Just make it a member variable of your Service class. Declare it at the top and set/check it in `playSong`;

Comment: I've updated the corresponding part of the class. What's wrong? There is no change of URL....

Comment: Well, `code`if(created){`\code` must be in the second part of else

Comment: The switch is rather durable, don't know why... Otherwise, thanks. Now I want to call service onCreate, not by Click. Is it normal way to call onClickListener when creating Activity?

Comment: If you have another question it's better to close this one down and post a new one. Hopefully I have helped. Please consider marking my answer as accepted if it has. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/226762 Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your comment, it's because `created` is true after the first play so you never execute your `else` logic. Here's how I would do it, I don't think there's any need to store a seperate `created` value.

```
public String currenturl = "";

public void playSong(Context c, String url) {
    if (currenturl.equals(url)) {
        // it's the same
    }
    else {
        // it's not the same
        currenturl = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked also for some situations, when the player is not started yet. Then we don't have to stop it on switch (as in case we have currenturl yet). Will think more - it's a pity that the calling new url take big delay. Well, the answer is good. Thanks!